# LCD light white side bleed

Tags: laptop, display, lcd

My wife's laptop (HP ENVY 15t-j100) has not been used for months and been "sitting" on its left edge side for several months. Now, she turned it on and the left edge of the LCD shows a white light bleed, stronger at the corners. What could be happening? is it fixable?

Cheers
Jorge

UPDATE:
Here's a photo of the issue
[image]

Comment: An image of the issue would be helpful.

Comment: @Moab: Good idea. Unfortunately the laptop just decided to die on us... I'll attempt to check what is wrong and hopefully will be able to revive it. If not, i'll close this question. Thanks! :)

Comment: @Moab: Ok, it looks like it was a bad contact on the charger plug side, laptop is back online. I've added the photo as requested, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

That's hardware failure of some sort. Perhaps a seperation of the layers of the panel.

I would say that, absent expert skill and probably a clean room, you cannot repair this, and even if you do, the individual layers will be so fragile that you're more likely to make things worse than better.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of, a hardware failure. What I find strange is that the bleeding come from the edge facing up when the laptop was lying on the side and I had some hope it would not be permanent. I had hope it could be the liquid crystals that had "flowed" towards the other side, but since I do not know how LCDs work, it was just a guess :) thanks!